# how to specify a c++ function pointer that may accept boost::bind'ed functions

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to store a list of arbitrary callback functions using boost::bind to allow arguments specific for the callback:

eg:

```
void callback1(int something) {...}
void callback2(int onething,theotherthing) {...}
```

The callback system stores these in a container:

```
typedef void (*lpvFunc)();
// ...
std::map <int,lpvFunc>regged_callbacks;
```

and at some point the registration function:

```
registerCallback(int slot,lpvFunc cb) { regged_callbacks[slot]=cb; }
```

the problem occurs when I try to do the bind to adapt the callback

```
registerCallback(1,boost::bind(callback2,42,31337));
```

and shazbang I get compiler errors like:
...note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'boost::_bi::bind_t > >' to 'lpvFunc {aka void (*)()}'|

so what do I fix to make this work (since boost::asio seems to be able to accept things like these just fine in its pointers to callbacks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store a raw function pointer to a functor that has a capture. What you could do instead is store type-erased functors, without changing anything else:

```
 typedef std::function<void()> lpvFunc;
```

(or the [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html) if you're not on C++11)

Comment: what's the boost form of this since gcc 4.7.1 (mingw) does not yet have fully functioning c++11 support?  boost::function ?

Comment: @BrianJack: Your compiler certainly supports `std::function`, even if its overall C++11 support isn't quite complete. I've been using them in GCC 4.6 for years.

Comment: @BrianJack edited to add the link, which is what I meant to do the first time around.

Comment: thanks for the help I did get this working...  I wonder though if code to check for NULL as a "no callback" condition (eg: in the registerCallback function above if I test for cb==NULL and not register a callback in that case)

Comment: @BrianJack If `f` is either a `boost::function` or a `std::function` you can do `if (f) { /* call f */ } else { /* no function */ }`